# flutter run command issue. Please provide any resolution

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-pub

Getting this error when using flutter run command:
**pub get failed (1; The system cannot find the path specified.)**

Please help me to solve this issue. Nowhere I can find any article solving this issue.

Comment: Please attach error log

Comment: From where I can find error log?

Comment: Try this from from cmd, navigate to project root and run that command. let me know if that works

Comment: @VipiNNegi Which command?

Comment: flutter pub get

Comment: @VipiNNegi Same error. Its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was my Autorun value was occupied with anaconda.bat as I have previously installed Anaconda. So clearing the value resolved my issue.

Steps to be followed:

1. Open the Registry Editor (press windows key, type regedit and hit Enter) .
2. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun and clear the values.
3. Also check HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun.